# Selecting Text from an R string to create a new object

Tags: string, r

I'm relatively new to R, and I'm currently stuck.
I have observations that are made up of legal articles, fe:

```
BIV:III,XXVIII.1(b);CIV:2.
```

So I splitted them resulting in a string listing each observation and the legal articles used. This looks like:

ArtAGr   list of 400230

```
chr[1:2] "BIV:III,XXVIII.1(b)" "CIV:2"
chr[1:1] "ILA:2.3(b)"
chr[1:3] "BIV:IB.3(d)" "CIV:7,9" "ILA:VII.1"
```

The BIV and CIV would need to become my new variables. However, the observations vary, so some observations include both BIV and CIV, while others include other legal articles like ILA:II.3(b)
Now, I would like to create a dataframe from these guys, so I can group all the observations in a column for each major article. 
Eventually, the perfect dataframe should look like:

```
Dispute    BIV            CIV            ILA
1        III, XXVIII.1(b)   2            NA
2          NA              NA            II.3(b)
3        IV.3(d)          7,9            VII.1
4          II              NA            NA
```

So, I will need to create a new object grouping all observations who contain a text like BIV, and a O or N/A for those observations that do not use this legal article. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!
Sven

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show an example of what you want your data frame to look like based on this data.

Comment: Sure, thanks for responding! So the data currently is a string like:"BIV:III,XXVIII.1(b)" "CIV:2" However, for other observations some of these legal articles might return, and others pop in. The final dataframe should group the data by legal article: thus the columns should be `BIV    CIV` etc. beneath these I would like to have the exact articles, so for one observations it should look like  `III,XXVIII.1(b)   2    NA  IV.2` etc. Does this make it more clear? Thanks again!

Comment: You can split them again using : and store each of the first elements.  And then "filter" (I don't remember now the function to search in strings) to get which use the legal article.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure whether this would work though. The problem is that not all articles are used in each case. So I might lose the connection between the articles and the numbers. Also I would like to get 0 or NAs whenever the article is not used.

Comment: @user3361202 you might have missed this: `It would be helpful if you could show an example of what you want your data frame to look like based on this data.`  Right now you have no solution in the past four hours.  I'd bet you a cup of coffee that if you heeded the advice you'd have an answer in ~4 minutes. (well now this question is less likely to be seen so 4 minutes after you paste a comment saying you've updated).

Comment: @TylerRinker is so right. The audience for questions diminishes with time and eventually people will no longer see a question to which the questioner has not responded in a concrete manner. At this point you should edit your question (and DO NOT add further comments.) Editing your question lets you use the full formatting facilities and also moves it to the top of the recently edited postings which gets it viewed again bu a larger audience.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat Good call on the `DO NOT add further comments` I din't know that...useful info.

Comment: I assume your example data frame is based on multiple strings. Please provide them too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

```
# a vector of character strings (not the splitted ones)
vec <- c("BIV:III,XXVIII.1(b);CIV:2",
         "ILA:II.3(b)",
         "BIV:IB.3(d);CIV:7,9;ILA:VII.1")

# split strings
s <- strsplit(vec, "[;:]")

# target words
tar <- c("BIV", "CIV", "ILA")

# create data frame
setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(s, function(x) 
  replace(rep(NA_character_, length(tar)), 
          match(x[c(TRUE, FALSE)], tar), x[c(FALSE, TRUE)])))), tar)
```

The result:

```
              BIV  CIV     ILA
1 III,XXVIII.1(b)    2    <NA>
2            <NA> <NA> II.3(b)
3         IB.3(d)  7,9   VII.1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm so close right now! But I do get the errormessage "Error during wrapup: NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments". If you could help me with this, I would be so grateful!

Comment: @user3361202 I cannot find a solution since i don't know your actual data.